# Kotlin lambda parameter vs. abstract value

Tags: lambda, kotlin, readability

How is better to pass a lambda function to a class that is used as parent: to pass it as a parameter or to define it in the pasrent class as an abstract lambda and then override it in a child class?

To pass it as a parameter:

```
open class Weapon(val someFunction: () -> Unit) {
    ...
}

class TheWeapon() : Weapon({ ... }) {
    ...
}
```

Or to define it to define it in the pasrent class as an abstract lambda and then override it in a child class:

```
abstract class Weapon() {
    abstract val someFunction: () -> Unit;
    ...
}

class TheWeapon() : Weapon() {
    override val someFunction: () -> Unit = { ... }
    ...
}
```

So what solution is better to use?

Comment: Can you pass an `()->Unit` to the method instead?

Answer (score 3):

If you were going to use the second approach, why not just have a method with this type that you override? It seems that `TheWeapon` can supply the lambda itself and doesn't take it as a parameter, so you could just move the code from the lambda to an abstract function:

```
abstract class Weapon {
    abstract fun someFunction()
}

class TheWeapon : Weapon() {
    override fun someFunction() { ... }
}
```

---

If `TheWeapon` receives the lambda from an external source through its constructor, then you have to go the other way, and have `Weapon` take the lambda as a constructor parameter as well.

Comment: I pass the function to another object, so it's easier to understand the structure if the function is lambda. Also I define the function in 'TheWeapon' class, so it isn't necessary to pass it as a parameter. Isn't it easier to read the code if the the lamda is defined in the body of 'TheWeapon' as a val?

Comment: At the end of the day, that's gonna be up to you. I think an abstract method and its override looks pretty clean. If you need to pass a reference to this function around later, you can do that with a bound method reference of `this::someFunction` inside the `TheWeapon` class.